# Value of the sum (numerical analysis)

Tags: polynomials, derivatives, numerical-methods

Let $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n$ are different real numbers and $\omega(x) = (x-x_0)(x-x_1)\dots(x-x_n)$. Then what is the value of the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\omega''(x_k)}{\omega'(x_k)}$$

I know that $\omega'(x_i) = (x_i-x_0)(x_i-x_1)\dots(x_i-x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i+1})\dots(x_i-x_n)$, but have no clue for the second derivative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$w'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \prod_{i\neq k}(x-x_i)$$

$$w''(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\sum_{0 \leq j \leq n, j \neq k}\prod_{i\neq k, i \neq j}(x-x_i)\right)$$

so $$w'(x_k) = \prod_{i\neq k}(x_k-x_i)$$

$$w''(x_k) = 2\prod_{i\neq k}(x_k-x_i)\left(\sum_{i \neq k} \frac{1}{x_k-x_i}\right)$$

so $$\dfrac{w''(x_k)}{w'(x_k)} =2\sum_{i \neq k} \frac{1}{x_k-x_i} $$

then $$\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{w''(x_k)}{w'(x_k)} =2\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{i \neq k} \frac{1}{x_k-x_i} =0$$

because $\dfrac{1}{x_k-x_i}$ and $\dfrac{1}{x_i-x_k}$ will make each other disappear.

Comment: OK, thanks, but can you tell me where this coefficient $2$ in the formula for $\omega''(x_k)$ comes from? Shouldn't it be with coefficient $1$?

Comment: @brick take a polynomial of degree $2$ to verify, it should be $2$. Since second derivative of $(x-x_k)(x-x_j)$ gives 2

Comment: $w'(x_k)$ should have $x_k-x_i$ instead of $x-x_i$.

Comment: @martycohen corrected, thank you!